# Vim: stop text scrolling up when command bar expands

Tags: vim

Whenever I do something that makes the command line/last status bar increase in height (for instance, `:e <TAB>`), all the text in my vim session moves up.

This is fine, if a little distracting, when I'm working locally, but sometimes I'm working over a *very* slow pipe where I desperately need to minimise total screen updates. Is there a way to force the status bar to *overwrite* the lines above it, instead of shifting them up?

Answer (score 3):

This happens if you set `wildmode` to `list`
See

```
:h wildmode
:h wildmenu
```

You can change this by just setting it to a different value like `full` (which is the default)

```
:set wildmode=full
```

Comment: It looks like `:set wildmode=full` only uses the status bar to show completion options. Does that mean there's no way to _simultaneously_ have a full tab-complete/wildmode window _and_ stop it moving the text above it?

Comment: @eapi i am pretty sure thats just how wildmenu is implemented. So there is no way to change it without changing the source code.